# SQL optimise select case statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, optimization, coding-style, case

Is it possible to streamline the following case statement or do I already have it in it's most elegant form?

```
select case when Ks2en = '' then 'No KS2' else ks2en end as 'KS2',
       nullif(count(case result when '' then 1 end),0) as 'No Result',
       nullif(count(case result when 'U' then 1 when '1a' then 1 when '1b' then 1 when '1c' then 1 end),0) as '1/U',
       nullif(count(case result when 'U' then 1 when '2a' then 1 when '2b' then 1 when '2c' then 1 end),0) as '2/U',
       nullif(count(case result when 'G-' then 1 when '3c' then 1 end),0) as '3c/G-',
       nullif(count(case result when 'G' then 1 when '3b' then 1 end),0) as '3b/G',
       nullif(count(case result when 'G+' then 1 when '3a' then 1 end),0) as '3a/G+',
       nullif(count(case result when 'F-' then 1 when '4c' then 1 end),0) as '4c/F-',
       nullif(count(case result when 'F' then 1 when '4b' then 1 end),0) as '4b/F'
       **snip**
  from student join subject 
    on subject.upn=student.upn 
 where name='English'
 group by ks2en
 order by
case when ks2en = 'W' Then 0 Else 1 End,
    left(ks2en, 1),
    right(ks2en, 1) desc
```

It generates the following grid and I would like this result to remain the same:

```
KS2 No Result   1/U     2/U     3c/G-   3b/G    3a/G+   4c/F-   4b/F    **snip**
No  KS2         1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
2a  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2       1       **snip**
3c  1           NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
3b  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1       NULL    **snip**
3a  1           NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
4c  NULL        1       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
4b  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
4a  NULL        1       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
5c  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
5b  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
```

I've snipped the code and results for brevities sake, but the sql contains quite a few more cases in order to create the columns of totals.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this code improves performance, so I'm posting a different way to do it, that IMO is more elegant. I'm using `result in ([listofoptions])` instead of multiple `case ... when`, I don't think that the execution will change much.

```
select case when Ks2en = '' then 'No KS2' else ks2en end as 'KS2',
      nullif(count(case when result = '' then 1 end),0) as 'No Result',
      nullif(count(case when result IN ('U', '1a', '1b', '1c') then 1 end),0) as '1/U',
      nullif(count(case when result IN ('U', '2a', '2b', '2c') then 1 end),0) as '2/U',
      nullif(count(case when result IN ('G-','3c') then 1 end),0) as '3c/G-',
      nullif(count(case when result IN ('G', '3b') then 1 end),0) as '3b/G',
      nullif(count(case when result IN ('G+','3a') then 1 end),0) as '3a/G+',
      nullif(count(case when result IN( 'F-','4c') then 1 end),0) as '4c/F-',
      nullif(count(case when result IN( 'F', '4b') then 1 end),0) as '4b/F'

from student 
inner join subject 
   on subject.upn=student.upn 
where name='English'
group by ks2en
order by
case when ks2en = 'W' Then 0 Else 1 End,
    left(ks2en, 1),
    right(ks2en, 1) DESC
```